# Stuck in a lava death loop. How do I get out?

Tags: trailmakers

While in a hovercraft in Trailmakers, your character automatically saves its position. there is a bug that allows this to happen while over lava. If you die 2-3 times in a row with a vehicle, the game will spawn you without a vehicle. This can end you up in a lava death loop if you switch vehicles. I was unable to find a solution for this but I found a [bug report](https://forums.kleientertainment.com/hot-lava-bug-reporter/hl-beta-reports/death-loop-r5380/) for it. It is fixed so it will be in the next release but it is impossible to get out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few minutes, I figured out the solution although it was not obvious. when you go to the main menu and reload the world, you always spawn at a checkpoint (i think) so you can just exit to main menu and rejoin and you will be fine.